# Application closing Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, error-handling

I'm creating a small android project. I'm new to java and android. When trying to open another activity in android application after 5 seconds of initial launch, instead of opening activity mentioned in intent, my application is getting closed.

My java code for opening another intent looks as follows for the activity to be opened.

```
Thread timer = new Thread() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent("com.mycompany.trial2.Third Activity");
            startActivity(openStartingPoint);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: where is your logcat???

Comment: Process: com.mycompany.trial2, PID: 28227
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.mycompany.trial2.ThirdActivity }

Comment: And my manifest file looks as follows

Comment: for the activity<activity
            android:label="Third Activity"
            android:name=".TextPlay" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="com.mycompany.trial2.ThirdActivity" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Answer (score 1):

There is a space in the name of class in your intent. I think that is creating the problem.

You should replace this:

```
Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent("com.mycompany.trial2.Third Activity");
```

with

```
Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent("com.mycompany.trial2.ThirdActivity");
```

This space in the name would have caused a ActivityNotFound Exception and closed your application. 
Also check that have you declared this activity in the AndroidMAnifest.xml this may also cause problem.

If this is not the problem please post your logcat.

Comment: post the logcat and please check that have you declared this activity in the AndroidMAnifest.xml

Comment: Process: com.mycompany.trial2, PID: 28227
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.mycompany.trial2.ThirdActivity }      I've declared my manifest file as below<activity
            android:label="Third Activity"
            android:name=".TextPlay" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="com.mycompany.trial2.ThirdActivity" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: You declared the name as "Third Activity" but calling "com.mycompany.trial2.ThirdActivity" please mention the full path in the manifest i.e "com.mycompany.trial2.ThirdActivity". It is the cause @sudhakarreddy just change the name field in the activity tag with the above mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

```
There was two chances for problems.
1. you didn't register your activity in android manifest file. so, Register your activity in manifest file. 

2.Try the following code
Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent("SecondActivity.this,ThirdActivity.class");
 startActivity(openStartingPoint);
```